# How to use repeat.for on definition list?

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia, it's pretty simple to create a ul or ol like so:

```
<ul>
  <li repeat.for='item of items'>${item}</li>
</ul>
```

But what if `item` is an object with, let's say a name and description, and I want to do a definition list? The `repeat.for` attribute repeats the element it's on, but in the case of a `<dl>` I would want to repeat a `<dd>` and a `<dt>` per iteration on the list.  I can't find any relevant syntax to help me with it, or any idea where to begin with it.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When there isn't a natural single wrapping element, you can just use a `template` element to wrap the stuff that needs repeating.

```
<dl>
  <template repeat.for="item of items">
    <dd>${item.foo}</dd>
    <dt>${item.bar}</dt>
  </template>
</dl>
```